# NTFS recovery after DD to disk

Tags: external-hard-drive, ntfs, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

I have an external USB drive that is failing. However, I managed to save the contents of the disk using `dd`. The drive was formatted as a single NTFS partition but the partition table is broken; OS (Win7 and Ubuntu) only recognize the drive as being un-partitioned. [DiskInternals NTFS Recovery](https://www.diskinternals.com/ntfs-recovery/recovery-how-to.shtml) 3.7 managed to identify a lot of files, but asks me to pay if I want to recover them. Before I spend money on this, can someone recommend a way to get my files back using freeware only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It's a recovery utility for linux (and Windows) that can work with disk images.

The website i linked should contain all information you need. If you are unpatient try this:

```
#~> testdisk your_image_file.dd
```

You will see a menu that's quite easy to understand. But please remember: **Always work with a copy. Do not work with your (hopefully not) only backup!**

Comment: worked like a charm, thx for your help!

Comment: I'm glad i could help!